# Hiding a scrollbar in a div

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way using css to hide a scrollbar **while still keeping its functionality**? Even make it transparent or the same color of the background will be fine. Do I have to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't get it - how can the user use a hidden scrollbar?

Comment: You can do this in jQuery using .scroll()

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ / http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Comment: @thirtydot Wow they are really slick man, nice find!

Comment: yes, only with just CSS. I'm familiar with the JS solutions.

Comment: So your actual question seems to be: "How can I skin/theme the native scrollbars with CSS?" -_-

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example.html Looks like you have to use JavaScript for this. The mousescroll event should be your best bet.

Comment: but I can't theme a scrollbar if it is in a div.

Comment: What is your actual aim here? You need to explain, clearly, what you want.

Comment: There are no pure CSS solutions to this you must have some sort of JS to do these advanced modifications...

Answer (score 6):

```
.className {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

The user will have to scroll using the mouse wheel I believe

Compatible with IE too...

Comment: Are you sure this works? I set the body of this page to the properties that you specified and I couldn't scroll in either direction.

Comment: @colondotcom - Right you are, it only seems to chop off the content.

Comment: @myxospsm - Why do you want to hide scrollbars but allow scrolling that would be ridiculously bad for accessibility?

Comment: do you mean the accessibility of disabled persons or the accessibility in the context of UI confusion? as per the UI confusion there won't be a problem, and this is just a theoretical question.

Comment: In both scenes, I was trying to find a practical application for such a piece of code...

Comment: well, I have a feed inside a div, There is a visual sign on the screen in the form of half seen item, so the user knows he can scroll down (or so I hope)

Comment: Ahh okay - understood now, all you really needed was a fancy scrollbar of some sort like @thirtydot posted

Answer (score 2):

`<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;"></div>`

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: You probably shouldn't be disabling scrollbars for scrolling content anyway or you're gonna confuse the dumb people.