# Independently scrolling div columns with images that extend beyond div width?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to create a page with two columns of images that scroll independently. I've built a simple two-column div layout with each column floating with 50% width and 100% height. The overflow is set to auto, so the content scrolls independently, but images wider than the container are cut off within the div.

Is there any way to achieve such an effect where the divs scroll independently and are able to have images that extend beyond the container? Or is there perhaps another direction to pursue?

Thank you!

--
Edit: Image for better explanation

What I mean by the overflow cutting off is that images wider are essentially cut off at the scrollbar, what I'm trying to achieve can be seen in this image, with each column being able to scroll independently ( I suppose with the mousehweel):

[image: Two Column Mockup]

Comment: What do you mean that the images get 'cut off'? With overflow: auto, you should be able to scroll horizontally to view the entire image as well?

Comment: does it happen with overflow:scrollable also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you'd think would work is:

```
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: scroll; /* or auto */
```

But this doesn't appear to function like you'd think/hope.  See this page for a grid of all possible overflow x/y combinations:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

So - I believe the answer is you'd have to:

```
1) give each box a height
2) give each box overflow-y:scroll; /* or auto */
3) use css positioning to place the boxes where you want
```

That should a) have the boxes in the correct place, but b) allow them to be side by side without a set width, and without needing float (which you can't get a consistent result w/out a set width in this case)

This would also have each box just auto-fit the width of the images, therefore they won't be cut off horizontally, but will still scroll vertically.

Comment: Thanks! Should I use absolute positioning? A number of combinations I'm trying isn't giving me the proper effect. You are right, i was hoping to use overflow-x: visible, but it also isn't working. The problem I'm finding without using floats/widths is that the div is taking over the entire width and pushing the right column down below the left.

Comment: @waffl - yes, if you absolute position each image-container box, they will be exactly where you want them, and with the info in my answer above, they'll a) be able to scroll vertically, but b) not get cut off horizontally.

Comment: OK Great, finally, is there any way to make the scrollbar invisible?

Comment: @waffl - not with CSS - you can with Javascript though - that question has already been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963219/hiding-a-scrollbar-in-a-div