# How to make a JQueryMobile-based application have a "touch" behavior in a desktop browser

Tags: jquery-mobile, touch

I am using JQueryMobile to build an application that will mainly run on a Linux-based touch device with Firefox.

My issue is that, with JQM, when page contents cannot fit on the screen, the web browser displays a vertical scrollbar [displays a vertical scrollbar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-performance.html)

There is no such issue with Sencha and Dojo. They both behave like if they were running on a touch-based device, even with desktop web browser (reduce the height of your browser window) :

- [Sencha scrolling list](http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/list)
- [Dojo scrolling list](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html)

So, how can I make JQM to be touch-friendly when running on a desktop web browser ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963219/hiding-a-scrollbar-in-a-div) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no really good JS and/or CSS solution for this issue.
Hiding the scrollbars with CSS (*overflow-y: hidden;*) prevents scrolling and mess JQM touch events.

I found a workaround by using a Firefox plugin (Grab and Drag), which is an acceptable solution since I control the device that runs the browser.

It works fine, but it is not a pure JS/HTML/CSS solution...